# Web Socket not opening in iOS with objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, websocket

I'm trying to open up a web socket in iOS, but when I print out the `readyState` of the socket, it either returns `connecting` or `closed` if I wait a few seconds to print it.

```
-(void)openSocket {
    self.socket.delegate = self;
    [self.socket setDelegateDispatchQueue:self.fvccWebsocketQueue];

        FVLoggerTrace(@"Opening web socket");
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.101.1:8080/api"]];
        NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:self.retryInterval];

        self.socket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:urlRequest];
        ++self.connectAttempts;
        [self.socket open];
        readyState = [[self socket] readyState];

    }
```

the URL can open in safari and displays the JSON data, but for some reason the socket isn't connecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to configure the url for websocket making `ws://192.168.101.1:8080/api/ws`